# Why call shm_unlink first before calling shm_open?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have seen the following code pattern in a legacy project:

1. Check whether the shared-memory has been created with name "/abc":

   ```
   int fd = shm_open("/abc", O_RDWR, 0777);
   if(fd != -1)
   {
     close(fd);
     return -1;
   }
   ```
2. Remove an object previously created by `shm_open()`:

   ```
   shm_unlink("/abc");
   ```
3. create a shared memory object:

   ```
   fd = shm_open("/abc", (O_CREAT | O_RDWR), S_IWUSR);
   ```

## Is Step 2 redundant?

The code can run into Step 2 because the shared-memory object doesn't exist for "/abc". In other words, the code returns if the object does exist. Why should we explicitly call shm_unlink to remove the non-existing object?

## Can we shorten the three steps to just one?

I think we can proceed as follows, where we use the flag `O_EXCL` to check whether there exists an old memory object and create it if it doesn't exist at all.  The [`shm_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) man page says:

> ### `O_EXCL`
>
> If O`_CREAT` was also specified, and a shared memory object
>                         with the given name already exists, return an error.  The
>                         check for the existence of the object, and its creation if
>                         it does not exist, are performed atomically.

So it should be okay to replace all the code above with a single line:

```
int fd = shm_open("/abc", O_RDWR | O_EXCL, 0777);
```

Is that correct?

Comment: You *should* replace the original sequence, since it contains a race window that could be exploited by another process to gain access to the shared memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the Step 2 redundant?

It is. It serves no purpose.

Besides this "check-for-existence" is prone to [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) vulnerability.

> Can we shorten the 3-step above as a single step

Yes. That's the right way to go about it. But you'll also need `O_CREAT` flag (which is missing in your code).